# Mock File moving in Junit

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have following lines in my method and I want to write Junit test case on the method. Can any one guide me how to mock it or how to skip

```
Files.move(source, target);
```

It is actually moving the file under src/test/resources.

Comment: you can use PowerMock for mocking static methods or you may extract `Files.move()` to some method object and mock it with Mockito library. I would choose second one.

Answer (score 1):

With Mockito 3.4.0 and newer versions it is possible to [mock static methods](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#48).

Here's a quick example[1]:

```java
@Test
void lookMomICanMockStaticMethods() {
  try (MockedStatic<Buddy> theMock = Mockito.mockStatic(Buddy.class)) {
    theMock.when(Buddy::name).thenReturn("Rafael");
    assertThat(Buddy.name()).isEqualTo("Rafael");
  }
}
```

---

[1] *Example taken from the blog by [Andrei Solnetsev](https://asolntsev.github.io/en/2020/07/11/mockito-static-methods/).*

Answer (score 0):

If PowerMock or Mockito 3.4.0 or newer (which I strongly recommend) is not available to you you could check if you can change your code a bit.

So if possible change your code to wrap the static call and mock that wrapping method, so erapping like:

```
public Path myMove(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)) {
   return Files.move(source, target, options);
}
```

and there should not be any problem to mock `myMove`.